# Mapping for columns names to rows

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know how to change my columns to rows and rows to column.
Here is an img of what i'm trying to achieve.

[image]

```
USE [master]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Main](
    [RowDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Level_1] [int] NULL,
    [Level_2] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Objective:

-RowDate will become a distinct column.
-Level_1 Level_2 will be distinct Row Header

Here is what I have which is far from guides but it's far from what i'm trying to achieve.

```
SELECT  countt, Level_Details
FROM [master].[dbo].[Main]
UNPIVOT (
countt FOR  Level_Details IN (
    Level_1, Level_2
    )
) unpvt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right path... First Unpivot your data, and then Pivot

However, I'm assuming you'll need dynamic columns, thus the Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select Level_Type,RowDate,Value
         From  YourTable 
         Unpivot (Value for Level_Type in ([Level_1],[Level_2]) ) Unpiv
      ) Src
 Pivot (sum(Value) for RowDate in ('+ Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([RowDate]) From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') +')) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

```
Level_Type  2019-01-20  2019-01-21
Level_1     40          20
Level_2     80          30
```

Comment: @kelv Happy to help.  I learn something every day here.  That's the fun part  :)